# How to add a layer control on leaflet by iterating through a df?

Tags: python, dataframe, leaflet, maps, folium

I have a specific column in my df with 4 unique values. I would like to add a feature group layer control to filter markers based on those four values. My code is:

```
m = folium.Map(location=it_coords, zoom_start=6,tiles='openstreetmap', control_scale=True,
                     prefer_canvas=True)



mc = MarkerCluster().add_to(m)
feature_group = FeatureGroup(name= "Monumenti")
for grp_name, df_grp in df.groupby('Tipologia personaggio'):
  print(grp_name)



for i in range(0,len(df)):
    html=f"""
        
        """
    iframe = folium.IFrame(html=html, width=200, height=200)
    popup = folium.Popup(iframe, max_width=2650)


    folium.Marker(
        location=[df.iloc[i]['Latitude'], df.iloc[i]['Longitude']],
        popup=popup,
        icon=folium.Icon(color=color, icon='info-sign')
        """)
    ).add_to(mc)
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: better create minimal working code (with example data in code) which we could simply copy and run - to test it and create solutions.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.